# How does the gravitational strength of the universe compare to that of a black hole?

Tags: gravity, black-holes, big-bang

A bit of a weird question, but at the moment after the big bang, how much gravity would a person 'standing', say a metre away experience compared to one standing a metre away from the centre of a black hole (say the supermassive one at the centre of our galaxy). I know it's beyond the event horizon, so I would mean from a theoretical perspective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> at the moment after the big bang, how much gravity would a person 'standing', say a metre away experience

The Big Bang didn’t happen at a point, so you can’t be one meter away from it.  The Big Bang model is one of a homogeneous and isotropic universe in which spacetime curvature invariants are the same at every spatial location. The curvature gets weaker with time, but not with distance, because there is no  “center” to be distant from.